# RESTful Java based webservice to handle huge data.

Tags: java, rest

I have an existing system - COBOL + DB2(Mainframe).

I am trying to create a new system - Java + DB2(Mainframe).

At the moment, I am trying to use Java to execute stored procs (on the DB2 mainframe). The stored procs pull data and that I am trying to return as the result of a RESTful web service. Dataset is running into 2 million or so. My system would be fine if it can handle 10 million.

I know multiple ways of creating Java based RESTful web service, however I have not handled this amount of data earlier i.e. 10 million. Can anyone please suggest what would be the best tool / framework (in the Java realm) to handle this amount of data.

I have already gone through the following links

1. [How to handle huge data in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266044/how-to-handle-huge-data-in-java)
2. [How to handle huge data from a REST service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608974/how-to-handle-huge-data-from-a-rest-service)

I am polling this group to see if there are other options available? 
Thanks.

Comment: where exactly are you problems? What have you tried? Which tests have been run? What frameworks are you using? How are you accessing your databases? Also : [*click](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*click](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: k im guessing since you dont even bother to communicate you dont even know the answers to these questions yourself ;)  I think it might be best to avoid "huge data" in your case ...